# using geom_line() to show two lines from one data frame

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame. df

inside the data frame there is a column called cars inside of cars there are two attributes(?) red and blue. so it looks something like this

```
day_of_week cars
monday      red
tuesday     blue
monday      red
sunday      red 
saturday    blue
friday      red
```

I am trying to plot days_of_week using ggplot geom_line() using cars code to show the count of red and blue for each day of the week.

`ggplot(df, aes(day_of_week, color = cars)) + geom_line(stat = "count")`
but i get the error `geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?`
and the graph just comes up blank. I managed to fix it by splitting up red and blue into to df because if i use `group =1` it just combines them together into one line. if i use `group = cars` there is no overlap with the lines

```
df_red <- filter(all_trip_v3, cars == "red")
df_blue <- filter(all_trip_v3, cars == "blue")

ggplot(df_red, aes(day_of_week, group =1, color = cars)) + geom_line(stat = "count")+ 
 geom_line(data = df_blue, mapping = aes(day_of_week, group =1, color = cars), stat = "count")
```

this fixed it. but is there a better way to do it from one data frame? instead of having to split it into two?

Comment: Could you please share your dataset using `dput(df)`?

Comment: Did you try `group = cars`?

Comment: @RobinGertenbach I did. However, when I do it that way the data doesn't overlap.  One line is totally on top of the other.

Comment: @Quinten As soon as possible! I don't have the data in front of me right now

Comment: @RobinGertenbach I fixed it using `group = interaction(cars)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to have found an answer to my own question.

After doing more searching I was able to combine and show both lines the way I wanted to using `group = interaction(cars)`

so my code looks like : `ggplot(df, aes(day_of_week, group = interaction(cars), color = cars)) + geom_line(stat = "count")`